# Title of book about a girl who charmed dragon-like creatures?

Tags: story-identification, books

It was about a girl who had been able to charm several dragon-like creatures, which had been believed to be impossible. Most people hadn't even believed that the dragon-like creatures even existed until she had arrived back with a broken hand and several of the creatures following her. 
The book also had something to do with music, and was the first of a trilogy. I read it a few years ago but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like Anne McCaffrey's Harper Hall Trilogy, specifically the first book, *Dragonsong.*  The plot follows a teenaged girl named Menolly with a talent for music.  Her rural family has discouraged her from singing or playing instruments because they feel that is men's work.  At one point she stumbles on a hatching nest of fire lizards (basically small dragons) and saves them from the rising tide.  She raises them and after a severe injury to her hand (not broken- cut very badly), she leaves home permanently.  She is trapped outdoors during threadfall (an environmental hazard) and rescued by a man who is basically a local aristocrat.

Comment: Beat me to it.  It's almost an exact match.

Comment: That's the one, thanks.